# Problemas al convertir consulta mysql a mongodb

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, mongodb

tengo un problema al tratar de interpretar una consulta en sql a mongodb, resulta que tengo una tabla llamada carros que tiene las siguientes columnas  , lo que necesito es que me traiga una lista de carros cuya sumatoria de sus campos  sea menor a una variable, logre solucionar ese problema con esta consulta sql:

```
SELECT placa, capacidad
FROM (SELECT placa, capacidad, @t := @t + capacidad total 
        FROM cars CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t := 0) i
        ORDER BY id)q
WHERE total <= 50
```

Pero no logro conseguir que funcione en mongodb, si me pueden ayudar a convertir esa consulta sql a mongodb se los agradecería.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar lo que has tratado?

Comment: Veo un poco complejo de realizar partiendo de que la consulta que muestras nace en una base de datos *relacional* y tratas de extrapolarla a una base cjuya estructura es documental y no relacional

Comment: No tengo nada aun, solo lo conseguí con mysql y en mongodb aun estoy probando, lo unico que quiero es que me traiga todos los vehiculos cuya sumatoria de su campo capacidad no superen el valor de una variable x.

Comment: Considero que lo mas conveniente en este caso es no pensar en forzar esa consulta de MySQL a Mongo, sino que agregues la estructura de tu documento y partiendo de ahí con la doc de este último trates algo, una vez que avances algo edites y agregues

Answer (score 0):

depende como tengas estructurados tus documentos en MongoDB 
una solución podría ser:

```
db.nombreColeccion.find({campo:{$lt:variable}}, {placa:1, capacidad:1})
```